# Idempotents central or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a nil-clean ring with unity such that $R/J(R)$ is reduced, where $J(R)$ is the Jacobson radical of $R$. Is it true that $R$ is abelian, i.e. the idempotents are central? (By *nil-clean* I mean each element is the sum of a nilpotent element and an idempotent element.)

By the first hypothesis, we could infer that each nilpotent element falls into $J(R)$. Also, by a nil-clean representation of  $a-1$,  where $a\in R$  is an arbitrary element, one deduces that each element is the sum of a unit and an idempotent.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Not immediately sure about the final answer, but I can see one necessary condition for it to be true. If all idempotents were central, then $J(R)$ would have to be nil: under the hypotheses each $j\in J(R)$ is expressed as $j=n+e$, but if $e$ is central, then $j-n=e\in J(R)\implies e=0$, so that $j=n$.

Comment: I think then it also follows that $R/J(R)$ is a Boolean ring.

Comment: @rschwieb Alexander J. Diesl has proved that $R$ being nil-clean is equivalent to $J(R)$ being nil and $R/J(R)$ is nil-clean: Journal of Algebra 383 (2013) 197–211, hence, reduced-ness of $R/J(R)$ makes it Boolean.

Comment: It's an interesting situation: the quotient ring is made entirely of central idempotents, all of which lift to $R$. Not sure this is a relevant feature or not.

Comment: Is this an exercise somewhere or an original research question? Don't worry: I'm not looking for some reason to close or modify it. I think it's a very interesting question.

Comment: @rschwieb: The subject appears in Theorem 4.20, of the article "Feckly Reduced Rings" , Hacettepe Journal of Mathematics and Statistics, Vol (44) (2) (2015), 375-384, by B. Ungor et al.